# wait for a process to finish inside an ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem() function

Tags: c#, asp.net, process, threadpool

Im doing a web application that will play a media.
  I have a class A that contains a method ,say MyMethod:

```
public void MyMethod()
        {
            .....
            Process proc = ....
            ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
            {
                proc.WaitForExit();
                proc.Close();
                .....

             },null);
          }
```

in code behind of my page I will call this method that will run the process and then will play the media, the process converts file to .flv type.My problem is becoz im using an asynchronous system,even if the thread didnt finish its work on unload, the page will load but without playing the media. How can i wait for the process inside the ThreadPool to terminate ? and THEN load my page ?? thanks alot.

Comment: If you want to wait for that code to finish, why are you queuing a thread pool task to do it in the first place?

Comment: i want it to finish before loading the page

Comment: So why don't you call `WaitForExit` at the last point before the page would load?

Comment: the waitforexit is inside the threadpool.. and on load Im calling this function plus other things

Comment: But *why* is the WaitForExit in the thread pool? There's no point in having it there, as far as I can see.

Comment: oke as i understand from you and Samuel that when we use Threadpool theres no need for the wait .thanks for the help

Comment: No, it's the other way round - when you want to wait, there's no need to use the thread pool.

Comment: yes,I was just editing my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want your asp.net resqponse to wait for the process result, call WaitForExit directly. Don't use the ThreadPool.

If for some reason you feel you absolutely need to use the ThreadPool, you can use a ManualResetEvent to wait for the result in the calling thread.

Comment: i did two methods.. one synchronous, one asynchronous. ive got no prob with the synchronous.. i used waitforexit... but m facing a problem with the threadpool.. ill check the manualresetevent